# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 + Gradle: Cannot Compile Groovy Files

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, gradle, intellij-14

Each time I attempt to create a new IntelliJ 14.1.4 project on Windows with Gradle integration I receive the following error during the 'Make' command when I have any Groovy source files included in the project...

```
Error:Cannot compile Groovy files: no Groovy library is defined for module 'GradleCommandLine'
```

I have tried:

- Creating a Gradle project through the new project wizard in IntelliJ, choosing Groovy as a an 'Additional Library'
- Creating a new Gradle project outside of IntelliJ using the `gradle init --type groovy-library` command, then opening IntelliJ which finds the gradle.build file and automatically links to the project
- Converting an existing project that was working with the IvyIDEA plugin to a Gradle build
- I have tried adding (made sure) my groovy-all library as a 'Global Library' within the project structure

Each of these gave me the same 'Cannot compile Groovy files' error.

What does work:

- I can run the `gradle war` command which compiles correctly and I can deploy the build war to an application server (in my case Tomcat 7.0.47)

However in watching the [Getting Started with Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA 13](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Euo6xzCwY4) (they do not have one for IntelliJ 14) demo video, they are able to just run the standard 'Make' and add the unexploded war as a build artifact.

Also had a colleague using the Mac version of IntelliJ 14.1.4 do the same 'I have tried' attempts above and he did not run into any issues. They even imported the same project I was having issues with and it was able to do the 'Make' without any changes to settings.

Comment: From Intellij Support: Was encountering error 'Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-bin.zip'.'    Pointing to local Gradle installation solved issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointing to local Gradle installation solved issue. There was an issue with a corporate proxy preventing the Gradle distribution from installing properly.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am new with Intellij, groovy and gradle. Everything is quite confusing. Could you please guide me how exactly can i solve this problem?  Thanks in advance. :)